# Title case in Access

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I am trying to setup a form for data entry in Access 2010. In one of the field, I want the entry to be Title Case (with exceptions like the, on, of, in, at, a, an...). For example: If I enter: "my first ABC at washington high school", it should become "My First ABC at Washington High School".

```
Private Sub EventTitle_AfterUpdate()
EventTitle = StrConv(EventTitle, vbProperCase)
End Sub
```

Using the above code, I get "My First Abc At Washington High School".
How do I make it recognize the exception list and leave the manually entered Caps alone (ABC instead of Abc). Thank you very much for your time. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: You may have to write your own function that parses the string, and omits the specified exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

`StrConv` isn't smart, it can't know know abc isn't a word. You'll need to deal with each exception separately. You can deal with the exceptions using `Replace`, something like:

```
EventTitle = StrConv(EventTitle, vbProperCase)
EventTitle = Replace(EventTitle,"An","an")
EventTitle = Replace(EventTitle,"At","at")
EventTitle = Replace(EventTitle,"On","on")
EventTitle = Replace(EventTitle,"Abc","ABC")
...
```

Comment: What if next sentence will have "XYZ" and one, several weeks later "DUI" ?

Comment: How can the parser know? of course you have to hard code, or write some sort of exception code (like encasing the words you want StrConv to ignore in a rarely used character, like % or |

Comment: I don't think all the words need to be hard-coded. Certain know articles or prepositions yes - the rule of the function will be "*do not convert words from that list*" But for the rest should be another rule, for example "*if a word consists of all capital letters - do not convert it. Otherwise change first letter to capital and make the rest lowercase*". It needs to be flexible and nor rely on knowing all the words in English language

Comment: Thank you serakfalcon for your help, also thank you Yuriy, your suggestion is exactly what I meant to ask.